# jQuery - input value replacement

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following code which is supposed to target the `#newsletter` input, add the default text into it and then remove it when a user tabs / clicks into the input. However it doesn't seem to work, and I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
  var defaultText = "Your email address";
  $('#newsletter').val(defaultText).focus(function() {
      if (this.value == defaultText) {
          $(this).val('');
      }
  }).blur(function() {
              if (this.value == '') {
                  $('#newsletter').val(defaultText);
              }
  });
```

Comment: here's the jsfiddle for ur code http://jsfiddle.net/hkVub/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing closing brackets in your code:

```
$(function() {
    var defaultText = "Your email address";
    $('#newsletter').val(defaultText).focus(function() {
        if (this.value == defaultText) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $('#newsletter').val(defaultText);
        }
    });  // <-- check it here
});
```

By the way, the thing you try to implement is a placeholder for the form field. It is worth to read about [`placeholder`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute in HTML5.

Comment: Cheers! Hadn't heard of placeholder, will check it out!

Comment: @arulmr Thanks for edit though I can't consider it as helpful.

Answer (score 2):

}); missing at the end of code, so issue is due to unbalanced braces.

here is corrected version

```
$(function() {
    var defaultText = "Your email address";
    $('#newsletter').val(defaultText).focus(function() {
        if (this.value == defaultText) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $('#newsletter').val(defaultText);
        }
    });
});
```